# What is the meaning of × in statistics?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, inference, terminology, notation

What is the meaning of the symbol × in an ANOVA context?

More specifically what is the meaning of × in the following table?

```
Study        Condition MeanSource      SS     df MS    F     p 
Original     .700      Subjects        0.668  39 
Mirror image .621      Item            0.357   2 0.178 12.90 <.001
Unprimed     .567      Item × Subjects 1.078  78 0.014
                       Total           2.103 119
```

And how can I calculate SS for the third row in the table?

Comment: I am not sure about the specifics of the software you are using, but it looks to me as if it were representing an interaction term

Comment: @David I am reading this [article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758%2Fs13428-010-0049-5.pdf). The symbol appears in Table 1. I need to know how to calculate SS for the third row but I have no idea what they mean by Item x Subject

Comment: As far as my (limited) knowledge goes: The subject row indicates how variance is "explained" by subject, the item row indicates how variance is "explained" by item. Finally, the row "subject x item" indicates how much variance is "explaind" by considering subject and item simultaneously. For example, if you have subjects 1 and 2, and items A and B, the first row relates to changing from 1 to 2, the second one, to changing from A to B, and the third row, to changing among combinations 1A, 2A, 1B and 2B

Comment: @David In this case how can I calculate SS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That x is probably representing an [interaction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340825/understanding-interaction-between-two-variables) term.

You should really give us more information about the data (and the experiment which produced it), but the SS's here seems to be sequential SS's, as  $0.668+0.357+1.078
=2.103$. Note also that for the df's (degrees of freedom) from the table we have:  $119-78-2-39=0$, so there is **no df's left for error**. That means that the interaction term `Item × Subjects` here is confounded with Error.

The anova table shows that indeed the interaction is used as an estimate of error variance, since $ 0.178/0.014 = 12.71429$ and  `pf(12.71429, 2, 78, lower.tail=FALSE)` returns  `1.662293e-05`.  **How can it be allowable to use an interaction as error**? Again, it would help to know the specifics of this experiment, but:  Assuming this is a randomized experiment, with some `Subjects` randomized to some treatment group `Item`.  Then the interest is really in comparing the different treatments.  The `Subjects` are just some random persons/animals/whatever used to compare the `Item`s. We are not specifically interested in comparing different `Subjects`.

The act of randomization means that there should not be systematic differences between the subjects randomized to the different treatments, the subjects are in reality a random factor. **The act of randomization is what justifies the use of the interaction as error**.

Comment: +1, but it may be helpful to explain why the IxS SS are being used to form the F-statistic for the test.

Answer (score 0):

The original paper (cited in the link you provided) tells us that the data were collected using a "repeated-measures ANOVA" experimental design (see page 492, last paragraph).  To learn how to calculate the ANOVA table for data from such a study, read a textbook on ANOVA.  Probably a first or second course textbook would tell you how to do that.  (BTW, the column headings in your ANOVA table do not line up perfectly, making the table a bit confusing. See the table in the original article.)  The original paper is here: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Anna-Lisa_Cohen/publication/24187239_Long-Term_Repetition_Priming_of_Briefly_Identified_Objects/links/00b7d51a505f7c0c8f000000/Long-Term-Repetition-Priming-of-Briefly-Identified-Objects.pdf

Comment: No paper is cited in the question! How do you know the OP refers to this paper?

Comment: The original paper, mentioned by the OP in a comment, is "A tutorial on a practical Bayesian alternative to null-hypothesis significance testing", not the one you refer to.   (Also @kjetilbhalvorsen FYI).

Comment: @jbowman The paper the op referenced uses data from a named study.  The study Iink to is that study - it includes the methodology and the statistical analysis. I have clarified my answer to indicate that.